# Ubuntu 14.04 sound suddenly stopped, reinstall alsa, pulseaudio not helping

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, skype, alsa

I have recently successfully upgraded my ubuntu to 14.04.

However, I've realized today that the sound is not properly working. The sound stopped working while skyping.

I logged out and still no sound. I reinstalled pulseaudio and alsa-utils, the sound came for a while, but after skyping again suddenly gone.

Right now is not working. Those are my alsa settings:

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****

card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 0: ALC889 Analog [ALC889 Analog]

Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 1: ALC889 Digital [ALC889 Digital]

Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

and pulseaudio output:

E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.

E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.

I tried doing a alsa force-reload but it does not help either.

Checking the sound in system settings I can see all the devices but, of course, the test sound does not work.

I don't know what else to do since I'm not an expert at all in linux and the solutions I found did not fix the problem.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would like to add some more info. Now if I reboot the system the sound works for a while.

Comment: The output from the alsa-info.sh script might help us to determine your problem. You can get it here: http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Help_To_Debug

Answer (score 1):

Look like Alsa layer is ok but top layer Pulseaudio stops working.
To test this , when the sound stops, run this in a terminal:
`killall -9 pulseaudio`
This will stop pulseaudio process . By default, pulseaudio  will be relaunched automatically  , so, if it was a pulseaudio problem, sound should be ok after closing and reopening audio players (skype ) .

Does the sound stop only with Skype ? If yes , you try to disable Skype auto level .

Comment: Thanks for your response. But it doesn't work. I tried killall -9  pulseaudio and pulseaudio --kill / pulseaudio --start but the sound doesn't come back. 
All the output audio stops. It only comes back if I reboot the system. Logging out doesn't help.

Comment: I have installed pavucontrol to check more sound options and, well, the sound doesn't work but if I check the output devices when playing something I can see the sound being detected by the device.

Comment: The problem is not related to Skype since it happened also when playing a youtube video in my browser. Suddenly the sound stops and no audio can be listened in the computer.